# Outlook add-in in read mode opens verticalpanel instead of horizontal?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-app

With all the examples I load from github with read panels, all screenshots show a vertical panel in read mode. However in my OWA-account, all read mode panels are opened in vertical/right mode in stead of horizontal?! e.g. this one: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-LinkRevealer and https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-ScanForMe
According to all examples this is not possible. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Regards,
Rick

Answer (score 1):

Outlook has multiple types of add-in interface elements that appear differently.

The examples you linked to are contextual add-ins, which are horizontal. To get a vertical panel instead, you probably want a task pane.

- [Task pane](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook#launching-a-task-pane)

  - Vertical
  - Appears on the right side of the Office app window
  - Triggered by clicking an add-in command button in the ribbon
  - Example screenshot: [WoodGrove Bank Expense Trends add-in](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-WoodGrove-Expense-Trends)
- [Contextual add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/contextual-outlook-add-ins)

  - Horizontal
  - Appears as a text-only button above the item body in read forms
  - User can click the button to expand the button into your horizontal add-in
  - Button only appears if the mailbox item matches criteria you specify in the manifest, like the body matching a regex or containing a street address
  - FormSettings/CustomPane

    - This is what the [ScanForMe](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-ScanForMe) and [LinkRevealer](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-LinkRevealer) add-ins are showing
    - **DEPRECATED** and prevents add-in acceptance into the Office Store (see Detected Entity below for replacement)
    - Deprecation is not detected by [official Office Store Add-In Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-validator), which returns a false positive for manifests containing a CustomPane element as of 2017-06-05. Also FormSettings and Rule are required child elements of OfficeApp, so I'm not sure how that validation is supposed to work.
  - DetectedEntity

    - Not deprecated
    - Only works in OWA, **doesn't work** in Outlook for Windows or Mac
    - Requires `VersionOverridesV1_1`
- [Add-In commands](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook)

  - Button or dropdown in the ribbon
  - Can be used to show a task pane or run some headless Javascript
- [Module extension](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/extension-module-outlook-add-ins)

  - Button in the bottom-right mode switcher in Outlook, next to Mail, Calendar, and Tasks buttons

Answer (score 0):

The examples you have found are built on an older version of the outlook web add-in extensibility model. We encourage developers to use the vertical taskpane control instead of the horizontal pane. In the new taskpane model, we’ve improved discoverability by the inclusion of icons to represent the add-ins which are now clearly visible next to regularly used actions such as reply. (See [Add-in Commands](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/20/add-in-commands-in-owa-and-outlook-on-the-mac/))

If you are looking for more space on the screen because the taskpane is very narrow, you may use the [Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync?product=outlook&version=v1.4) to provide larger UI elements to your users.

Comment: Thanks, but do I understand it correctly that it is still possible to show a horizontal pane? Or is it just not possible anymore?